# How to sell digital goods (redeem codes) using Drupal?

Tags: commerce

I'm considering Drupal as a platform for a web project I'm working on. 
I'm looking for a way to sell redeem codes using [UberCart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart), [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) or some other module.

The client will be able to buy a single code or several codes and receive it/them by email.

Redeem code format : `201504[variable_value]`,  eg : `201504846, 201504965, 201504347...`

Any ideas on how to manage this? Will every code be considered as a product (unique SKU)?

I need to be able to import the codes into the Drupal store. How will I be able to achieve this? I buy the codes in bulk and get them in an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: if you're looking for a tutorial, this is the wrong place to ask - this site is designed to help answer specific questions about specific problems. A web search will yield numerous sources for what you want.

Answer (score 4):

There's a UC solution called [UC Product Keys](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_product_keys) out there for this particular use case, but you're better off avoiding it; the project has no 7.x version and is minimally maintained.

The Drupal Commerce equivalent is [Commerce Product Key](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_key)...

> This module lets sites implementing the Commerce module, attach
>   product keys to orders. Product keys / Vouchers are strings of text
>   that are used to unlock or activate a piece of software.
>
> Right now we have an entity that can be attached to a product and then
>   assigned via a rule to a product once it has been bought. The required
>   actions and rules events are fleshed out and simply require the wiring
>   up of the rules to meet you scenario.

It probably won't do everything you need (e.g. import license keys), but it should be a good starting point to build your own product key solution off of.

Answer (score 0):

I would **Not** use [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) (as in your question) for this. But instead use an approach as detailed below.

## Part 1 - Create nodes

Starting from your spreadsheet, you should be able to transform them (easily) in a CSV file. Use something like the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to automatically create a single node for each of your redeem codes you want to be able to sell.

## Part 2 - Use Light Shop

Use the [Light Shop](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightshop) module, a simple and lightweight e-commerce solution. Here is a quote from its project page:

> - Session-stored basket.
> - Adding to basket and its subsequent editing/checkout process is done using AJAX. Also it works fine when JavaScript is turned off.
> - Node based shopping. As the product can be assigned to any node type. One or more. With full support Field API features (regarding nodes).
> - Orders history. For each order will be created a separate node.
> - There is no dependence on other modules.
> - Full support for working with anonymous users
> - Integration with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

The ***Node based shopping*** could be a perfect fit for your nodes created as described in **Part 1**.